# How can I show the amount saved in Magento 2?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am trying to display amount saved on the catalog page for a Magento 2.0.2 website. However I'm not getting the calculation result displayed. I just get an empty space. I am editing the final_price.phtml in my theme file.

I didn't find any information in google as most results are for related to Magento 1 and the codes are throwing errors.

This is what my code looks like in the section which I am trying to do the calculations.

```
<span class="special-price"><span class="only-text">Only: </span>
    <?php echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
        'display_label'     => __('Special Price'),
        'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
        'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
        'include_container' => true,
        'schema' => $schema
    ]); ?>
</span>
<br>
<span class="old-price"><span class="rrp-text">RRP: </span>
    <?php echo $block->renderAmount($priceModel->getAmount(), [
        'display_label'     => __('Regular Price'),
        'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
        'price_type'        => 'oldPrice',
        'include_container' => true,
        'skip_adjustments'  => true
    ]); ?>
</span>
<span class="saving-price"><span class="saving-text">Saving: </span>
<?php
$wasPrice = $block->renderAmount($priceModel->getAmount(), []);
$nowPrice = $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), []);
  if ($nowPrice < $wasPrice){
    $saving = $wasPrice - $nowPrice; 
    echo $saving;
  }
?>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of using

```
$wasPrice = $block->renderAmount($priceModel->getAmount(), []);
$nowPrice = $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), []);
```

you should use

```
$wasPrice = $priceModel->getValue();
$nowPrice = $finalPriceModel->getValue();
```

$priceModel and $finalPriceModel refer to `/** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface $priceModel */` as you can see in line 17 in your final_price.phtml

then inside of the PriceInterface.php we'll see that getAmount() returns an object while getValue() just returns a number.

```
/**
 * Get price value
 *
 * @return float
 */
public function getValue();

/**
 * Get Price Amount object
 *
 * @return AmountInterface
 */
public function getAmount();
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this works well

```
<?php if ($block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>
    <span class="special-price">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
            'display_label'     => __('Special Price'),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'schema' => $schema
        ]); ?>
    </span>
    <span class="old-price">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($priceModel->getAmount(), [
            'display_label'     => __('RRP'),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'oldPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'skip_adjustments'  => true
        ]); ?>
    </span>
</span>
<br>
<span class="saving-price"><span class="saving-text"></span>
<?php
$wasPrice = $priceModel->getValue();
$nowPrice = $finalPriceModel->getValue();
$saving = $wasPrice - $nowPrice; 
$saving = number_format((float)($wasPrice - $nowPrice), 2, '.', '');
$savingpct = number_format((float)(100*(($wasPrice - $nowPrice)/$wasPrice)), 0);


  if ($nowPrice < $wasPrice){

    echo "You save: $ ".$saving. "<br />";
    echo $savingpct. "% Off";
  }
?>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue on category and search results pages on Magento 2. Here's what I eventually figured out. Hope it helps! (Note: this all falls within the **foreach** loop which iterates through each **$_product** within **$_productCollection**):

```
$regprice = $_product->getPrice();
$specialprice = $_product->getSpecialPrice();
$yousave = number_format((float)($regprice - $specialprice), 2, '.', '');
$yousavepct = number_format((float)(100*(($regprice - $specialprice)/$regprice)), 0);

if($yousave > 0): ?>
    <p class="you-save-statement">You save: $<?php echo $yousave; ?> (<?php echo $yousavepct; ?>%)</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```